# Let all windows stay in foreground

Tags: display, window, settings, focus

What can I do that all tabs stay in the foreground all the time?

Imagine you have two windows open; one is, for example, Google Chrome, this one is fullsize. The second one is a normal sized terminal. If I do something in the terminal it's in the foreground, but if I then click something in the browser, the terminal will go to the back. What can I do to hinder the terminal or any other window to going to the background when it loses focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on window's title bar (or `Alt + Space`) and select "always on top".
Actually, it will let your window be on top of all other windows which haven't got this option selected.